# Position of an image bigger than window size

Tags: html, css

I noted that a backgorund image is bigger than browser window, and it's positioned at some percentage, his assume a position that start out of the screen...
Check 
[this page](http://html.it/articoli/esempi/articoli_pro/534/3colPerc.html)

the background of the left column is a gif of 2000px, and this is the CSS rule

```
div#container{min-width: 550px;background: #FFF url(leftP.gif) repeat-y 25%}
```

In a normal/logical situation, the image should be positioned at (window size*25)/100 pixel, but in this case the image seems positioned in a negative coordinate (es. -50px)

So, when the image is bigger than window size, what the position expressed in percentage refers to? What's the formula that the HTML apply?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the background size property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

In your example above the 25% will apply to positioning, not size.

Comment: Yes, i know that it's apply to the position, but why it become negative?
It's like the position of the image is minor than ZERO, and smallest is the browser window size, minor is the position of the image (-10, -20, -30 etc etc..)